# Does the .NET 4 memory mapped API support alternate data streams?

Tags: .net, memory-mapped-files

Microsoft introduced a new System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles namespace in .Net 4. Does anyone know if it will support alternate data streams? Thx!

Comment: Have you encountered a problem? I'd just test and see.

Comment: Alternate?  It supports only MemoryMappedViewStream.  You can make it look like a Stream to any code.

Comment: Nobugz, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Alternate_data_streams_.28ADS.29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am pretty sure that no. FileStream's filename validation didn't accept alternate data streams paths, i think here it will behave the same. why do you need ADS?

Comment: ADS offers a wonderful mechanism for non-critical file-related storage. For example I could create a file index that can easily be recreated if the file was backed up.